# Ways to Fix Out Of memory Exception in Bitmap.createBitmap method

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I have the following code to convert a view to Bitmap to send it for printing.
It's throwing OutOfMemoryError on
***Bitmap.createBitmap***:

Failed to allocate a 43899852 byte allocation with 9531608 free bytes and 9MB until OOM

Is it possible to divide the problem, create smaller bitmaps and combines them, or some other tricks?

```
 private fun loadBitmapFromView(context: Context, v: View): Bitmap {
    val dm = context.resources.displayMetrics
    v.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    )
    v.layout(0, 0, v.measuredWidth, v.measuredHeight)
    val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            v.measuredWidth,
            v.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val c = Canvas(returnedBitmap)
    v.draw(c)
    return returnedBitmap
```

}

Comment: It would help if you posted the values of `v.measuredWidth` and `v.measuredHeight` to see how big the view is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still experimenting with this, but it seems that the limits might be OS version and hardware dependant (Older OS versions might create the bitmap in the VM heap which is much smaller)

On my Android 10 device the limit of a Bitmap is 2Gb as it seems to be allocated from Native memory not from the VM's memory (doing things with it might use VM memory and then a lower limit might apply)

So for just creating a bitmap 26000 x 20000 succeeds (1.9Gb) is the near the limit for this device.

But my thoughts on a solution for a similar problem.

1. Use a `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` this halves the memory required (2 Bytes per pixel instead of 4 Bytes) but this affects the colour quality, but this might be OK for you.
   (This allows you to create big resolution bitmaps, not sure how they will look)
2. Create a scaled down version. Normal printers or even screens won't probably noticed if you create a scaled down version.
   e.g. create the bitmap at half the size of the measured view and then set a scale on the canvas to draw at that scale.

One downside is that you don't seem to be able to catch these errors up front, so handling them and choosing an alternate strategy after OOM is hard.

(I will try and update this if my experimentation has some success)